# My App Is not retrieving a response from the server on upload

Tags: android, server, ion-koush

I have an app to upload Images to my company server I am Using koush Ion
for the upload Now the Issue is The Upload Itself Works the images are being uploaded to the server BUT I don't get a popup response from the server saying Upload Success etc.
The responses worked previously before i switched from APACHE to Ion

After I click Upload seemingly nothing happens But the image is uploaded to the server but there is no response from the server with the usual popups of Upload Successful etc.
The Code For the Response is in an ASP file

**UploadActivity**

```
package com.smartpractice.myapplication;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;

import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.koushikdutta.ion.Ion;
import com.koushikdutta.async.future.FutureCallback;


import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;



public class CameraActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
    private final int PICK_IMAGE = 12345;
    private final int REQUEST_CAMERA = 6352;
    private static final int REQUEST_CAMERA_ACCESS_PERMISSION =5674;
    private Bitmap bitmap;

    String myURL;

    private ImageView imageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);

        imageView =findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        Button fromCamera=findViewById(R.id.fromCamera);
        Button fromGallery=findViewById(R.id.fromGallery);
        Button upload=findViewById(R.id.upload);
        upload.setOnClickListener(this);
        fromCamera.setOnClickListener(this);
        fromGallery.setOnClickListener(this);


        if (!getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_ANY)) {
            fromCamera.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.fromCamera:
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M
                        && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                            REQUEST_CAMERA_ACCESS_PERMISSION);
                }else {
                    getImageFromCamera();
                }
                break;
            case R.id.fromGallery:
                getImageFromGallery();
                break;
            case R.id.upload:
                if (bitmap != null)
                    uploadImageToServer();
                break;
        }

    }


    private void uploadImageToServer() {

        Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder();
        builder.scheme("https")
                .authority("www.smartpractice.co.za")
                .appendPath("files-upload-ruben.asp")
                .appendQueryParameter("MyForm","Yes")
                .appendQueryParameter("ClientID", String.valueOf(R.id.clientid))
                .appendQueryParameter("Username",String.valueOf(R.id.emailtext))
                .appendQueryParameter("Pwd",String.valueOf(R.id.pwdtext));
               myURL =  builder.build().toString();

        File imageFile = persistImage(bitmap, "SP_Upload");
        Ion.with(this)
                .load(myURL)
                .setMultipartFile("SP-LOG", "image/jpeg", imageFile)
                .asJsonObject()
                .setCallback(new FutureCallback<JsonObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(Exception e, JsonObject result) {

                    }
                });
    }

    private File persistImage(Bitmap bitmap, String name) {
        File filesDir = getApplicationContext().getFilesDir();
        File imageFile = new File(filesDir, name + ".jpg");

        OutputStream os;
        try {
            os = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, os);
            os.flush();
            os.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Error writing bitmap", e);
        }

        return imageFile;
    }


    private void getImageFromCamera() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
    }


    private void getImageFromGallery() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                try {
                    InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData());
                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        } else if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                bitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA_ACCESS_PERMISSION) {
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                getImageFromCamera();
            }
        } else {
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        }
    }}
```

Comment: Please log the exception and result you have in `onCompleted`

Comment: @Ashish sorry I have been doing java and android for about 2 weeks can you elaborate if possible?

Comment: Put Log in your `onCompleted` Like this.
`public void onCompleted(Exception e, JsonObject result) {
 Log.e("Exception", e.getMeesage()) or Log.e("Exception", e);
 Log.e("result", result);
}`

And post the outcome from logcat

Comment: 2019-08-12 13:57:46.809 15840-15840/com.smartpractice.myapplication E/Exception: unable to parse json
I think this might be the problem because it is the only error how can i fix this

Comment: Please follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12860237/10182897) link you will find your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The request returns a string = "I am in", but callback expects JsonObject. Your server must return json format string.

```
Ion.with(this)
        .load(myURL)
        .setMultipartFile("SP-LOG", "image/jpeg", imageFile)
        .asJsonObject()
        .setCallback(new FutureCallback<JsonObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(Exception e, JsonObject result) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks dude, I realized that after awhile, I hardcoded a Toast Message into the app too work around that, thanks anyway